# How to run Airflow and Docker?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, airflow

I tried to learn how to use airflow with docker.I see some docs but I'm not sure what to do.Do I need to add some specific file ?
for example, I create a simple image that prints some text "hi". I want to use Airflow to print it every 5 hours. What do I need to do?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a dag which run each 5 hours (`schedule_interval="0 */5 * * *"`) and create a task from the operator [DockerOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html#airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker.DockerOperator) providing the image argument, and the cmd if you want to override the image command.